# How to control volume on Windows from Android device remotely?

Tags: windows-10, android, remote-control

I'm wondering is there a way to control volume from Android 9 on Windows PC (Windows 10) remotely via Wi-Fi?

Actually all I need is to lauch *nircmd.exe* on remote machine somehow.

It's not about using full remote access like RDP or VNC, it's about how to lauch any Windows script from Android device via one tap on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are apps that offer these functions using a variety of means. What research have you done so far?

Comment: I have found a lot of old app stuff that doesn't support Android 7+ so I decided to solve the problem manually.

Comment: Write a web interface and host it on your Windows machine that's able to execute what you want?

Comment: Is there a more easier way? I mean maybe Windows has a technology which allows to recieve scripts for further execution.